# How does `Module#autoload` and `Module#autoload?`work in ruby?

Tags: ruby

How does `Module#autolad` and `Module#autoload?`works couldn't understand by reading the below only:

> ***Module#autoload:*** Registers filename to be loaded (using Kernel::require) the first time that module (which may be a String or a symbol) is accessed in the namespace of mod.
>
> ***Module#autoload?*** - Returns filename to be loaded if name is registered as autoload in the namespace of mod.
> c**an anyone help me to understand the concept with some tiny code examples?

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```
$ echo 'class AutoloadDemo; end' > autoload_demo.rb
$ ruby -e "
> p autoload? :AutoloadDemo
> p defined?(AutoloadDemo)
> autoload :AutoloadDemo, './autoload_demo'
> p autoload? :AutoloadDemo
> p defined?(AutoloadDemo)
> p AutoloadDemo
> "
nil
nil
"./autoload_demo"
"constant"
AutoloadDemo
```

Explanation: `autoload` registers a "lazy loading" for a constant (that is the argument symbol of the `autoload` method); when the costant represented by that symbol (in the example `AutoloadDemo`) is encountered in the script, Ruby requires the file associated to that constant (the second argument of `autoload`). `autoload?` is nothing more than the answer to the question "is this constant registered for an autoloading?"

---

#### Constant registration

In Ruby a constant is a value which should be the same during the program execution; it  must start with an uppercase character.

The *constant registration* is what that the Ruby interpreter does when you call `autoload`: it says

> Ok, when I encounter this constant in the next executions, if it is
>   not defined, instead of raising a NameError I require this file and look
>   whether it defines the constant; if so, I continue the execution.

Comment: `register` and `constant` these words made me much confused in the doc.can you bit explain those alone?

Answer (score 0):

basically, autoload is a way to load a ruby file the first time a constant is used.  This can be useful for "delayed loading" or "just in time loading" the first time you end up using a constant.  See http://www.rubyinside.com/ruby-techniques-revealed-autoload-1652.html for some details.